# Is there a shortcut way to refer to elements in my DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="adminDialog" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a data-dismiss="modal" class="close">×</a>
         <h3 id='dialog-heading'></h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

I created this variable:

```
dialogDiv = $('#adminDialog');
```

I would like to change the text of the heading. If I want to do this do I need to 
use `$('#dialog-heading').text()`  or is there a shortcut way that is based on the dialogDiv variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has to be based on the dialogDiv then this is the best one I know

```
$("h3", $("#adminDialog")).text('new text');
```

Or

```
$("h3", dialogDiv).text('new text');
```

This selector tell you to find a **`h3`** within the scope of **`#adminDialog`**.

---

But you are using an id for the div, so no selector can top the direct selection. Like

```
$('#dialog-heading').text('new text');
```

Comment: h3 comes first?  I never saw this kind of selector before. Also can I just replace $("#adminDialog") with dialogDiv?

Comment: So $("h3", dialogDiv).text() would be okay? That's looks very clean to me :-)

Comment: @MarieJ, Yes it is OK and very clear way to select within a scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `dialogDiv` or `$('#adminDialog')` as they refer to same object. It only works if the `dialogDiv` is present in your current scope (meaning, if you've assigned it in a function, it is only available within that function)

Comment: A lookup by ID will be quicker than one based in `dialogDiv` though since ID lookups are most likely `O(1)`.

Comment: But what I was meaning is what's the cleanest way for me to set the H3 title. I think it looks a little more clean if I can use dialogDiv as a base but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: define clean, it's not 'written in stone'. If you need to use it for many things, you can save it in a variable, but if you only do one thing, just use the jquery directly, so you don't have all teh variables. And about the speed: you are looking at minor, minor, microoptimalization here, don't bother with that please.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have access to `dialogDiv` within the current scope, it is even prefered to use `dialogDiv.find("#dialog-heading").text("new text")`, as it wouldn't have to go through the entire DOM again, thus slightly more performent.

Comment: Wouldn't `$('#adminDialog')` be cached by jQuery?

Comment: @KooiInc Would it? I have always read that you should cache the object yourself for performance. Is the caching new or simply something I missed? Any good read on that?

Comment: You didn't miss anything, my bad, nothing is cached. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291841/does-jquery-do-any-kind-of-caching-of-selectors.

Comment: @KooiInc Ahh good, you made me confused there for a second :)

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on your needs.

Since your element has an ID, `$('#dialog-heading')` will be the fastest way to access it.

However, if you want to access *"the `<h3>` inside `#adminDialog`"*, better use `adminDialog.find('h3')`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have one `h3` child element in your `div#adminDialog`, you can also use a CSS selector:

```
$('div#adminDialog h3').text("bla bla")
```