# Jquery Cache Future Selector

Tags: jquery, caching, jquery-selectors

I know you can cache a selector to improve performance if your going to use it more than once by doing:

```
mySelector = $('#mySelectorId');
```

Is it possible to cache selectors that are going to be added in the future without doing the below?

```
var selector;

$('#something').click(function(){
    $('body').append('<div id="futureSelector"></div>');
    selector = $('#futureSelector');
})
```

Comment: why do you need that.?? for applying events to that.?? if it is then use .on() jQuery method

Comment: @Dipesh Parmar It would be for anything, such as .css() etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291841/does-jquery-do-any-kind-of-caching-of-selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think not, because jQuery method returns object. And you can't store object which doesn't exist.