# JavaScript OOP: use private member jQuery again or reselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

Let's look on this JavaScript code:

```
Person: function() {
    var element = null;

    this.init = function() {
        // select an HTML element created+ added to DOM in init()
        element = $("#justCreatedElement"); 
    };

    this.workingFunction = function() {
        // use private member `element`
        element;

        // create new variable and select again with jquery
        var element = $("#justCreatedElement");
    }
}
```

We can assume that the `init()` method gets called before any other method.

I have the following Question:

**1** In the `init()` I use JQuery to assign a HTML element to the private member `element`. Because `element` is visible for all methods I can just use it again in the method `workingFunction2()`. What is better coding standard:

**I** Using `element` private member in all member mehtods and even maybe write it in any member methof.

**II** Using `element` private member only to read in all member methods, except once, where it is set for the first time, here in `init()`. And if private member `element` must be changed use a mehtod called `changeELement()` but do not write it in a method where the user cannot know that it get written to.

**III** General avoid to use a member variable that holds JQuery selections and always select again in every mehtod

Or can somebody give me his own standards regarding this problem.

Comment: *"What is better coding standard...?"* Neither. Both. It completely depends on other factors. What's the cost of re-querying the DOM for the element? (With `getElementById`, it's really small; other queries can be more expense.) How often would you re-query if you re-queried? Will anything else *completely replace* the element? Are you doing this with tens of thousands of instances? I'm not actually asking you these questions, I'm just pointing out that the answer here is: "It depends."

Comment: It is in general a good Idea when working with a dedicated elements on differend places over-and-over again to store it in a variable. Regardless if working with plain JS or jQuery. But as @T.J.Crowder said before: "It depends". ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does jQuery do any kind of caching of "selectors"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291841/does-jquery-do-any-kind-of-caching-of-selectors)