# jQuery function is not working as per my expectation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

in my HTML I have two buttons one is previous and second is next button. it will be display next slide by clicking next button. it will be display previous slide by clicking prev button. I didn't know but sometime I need to click two times for going on previous slide. Can you please tell me why it happening? and How can I resolve it? I am weak in English so please apologize me if I made any Grammatical or Spelling mistakes.

jQuery code:

```
$("#next").click(function(){
    var pagenumber = $(this).data("page")-1;
    $("#page"+pagenumber).addClass("hide");
    $("#page"+$(this).data("page")).removeClass("hide");
    if($(this).data("page") == 3){
        $("#next").addClass("hide");
    }
    else{
        $('#next').data('page', $(this).data("page")+1);
        $('#prev').data('page', $(this).data("page")-1);
    }
    if($("#prev").data("page") > 0 && $("#prev").hasClass("hide")){
        $("#prev").removeClass("hide");
    }
});
$("#prev").click(function(){
    var pagenumber = $(this).data("page")+1;
    $("#page"+pagenumber).addClass("hide");
    $("#page"+$(this).data("page")).removeClass("hide");
    if($(this).data("page") == 0){
        $("#prev").addClass("hide");
    }
    else{
        $('#prev').data('page', $(this).data("page")-1);
        $('#next').data('page', $(this).data("page")+1);
    }
    if($("#next").data("page") < 3 && $("#next").hasClass("hide")){
        $("#next").removeClass("hide");
    }
});
```

Html code:

```
<div style="text-align:left"><a id="prev" class="hide" data-page="0">< PREV</a></div>
<div style="text-align:right"><a id="next" data-page="1">NEXT ></a></div>
```

Comment: Try to provide jsfiddle link

Comment: put an alert() in each click see whether the click events working properly

Comment: `console.log()` would be better.

Comment: @SirajAbbas  Yes click event is working properly and it value is 1 when prev button is starting to appear

Comment: @Rushabh Shah can you create a jsfiddle.

Comment: @RushabhShah you need to use existing values before you update them based on new page. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to optimize you code, utilized a techique [jQuery selector caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291841/does-jquery-do-any-kind-of-caching-of-selectors)

```
var $next = $("#next");
var $prev = $("#prev");
$next.click(function() {
  var pagenumber = $next.data("page") - 1;
  $("#page" + pagenumber).addClass("hide");
  $("#page" + $next.data("page")).removeClass("hide");
  if ($next.data("page") == 3) {
    $next.addClass("hide");
  } else {
    $next.data('page', $next.data("page") + 1);
    $prev.data('page', $next.data("page") - 1);
  }
  if ($prev.data("page") > 0 && $prev.hasClass("hide")) {
    $prev.removeClass("hide");
  }
});
$prev.click(function() {
  var pagenumber = $prev.data("page") + 1;
  $("#page" + pagenumber).addClass("hide");
  $("#page" + $prev.data("page")).removeClass("hide");
  if ($prev.data("page") == 0) {
    $prev.addClass("hide");
  } else {
    $prev.data('page', $prev.data("page") - 1);
    $next.data('page', $prev.data("page") + 1);
  }
  if ($next.data("page") < 3 && $next.hasClass("hide")) {
    $next.removeClass("hide");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In your code, you updated the page value before modifying the previous based on current next value.

Problematic :

```
else{
        // you updated next here
        $('#next').data('page', $(this).data("page")+1);
        // instead of using previous value you get updated value.
        $('#prev').data('page', $(this).data("page")-1);
    }
```

So try following,

```
$("#next").click(function(){
    var pagenumber = $(this).data("page")-1;
    $("#page"+pagenumber).addClass("hide");
    $("#page"+$(this).data("page")).removeClass("hide");
    if($(this).data("page") == 3){
        $("#next").addClass("hide");
    }
    else{
        $('#prev').data('page', $(this).data("page")-1);
        $('#next').data('page', $(this).data("page")+1);
    }
    if($("#prev").data("page") > 0 && $("#prev").hasClass("hide")){
        $("#prev").removeClass("hide");
    }
});
$("#prev").click(function(){
    var pagenumber = $(this).data("page")+1;
    $("#page"+pagenumber).addClass("hide");
    $("#page"+$(this).data("page")).removeClass("hide");
    if($(this).data("page") == 0){
        $("#prev").addClass("hide");
    }
    else{
        $('#next').data('page', $(this).data("page")+1);
        $('#prev').data('page', $(this).data("page")-1);
    }
    if($("#next").data("page") < 3 && $("#next").hasClass("hide")){
        $("#next").removeClass("hide");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this snippet will helps you. Your js code is working I just minor changes for click functionality.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#next", function(){
  var pagenumber = $(this).data("page")-1;
  $("#page"+pagenumber).addClass("hide");
  $("#page"+$(this).data("page")).removeClass("hide");
  if($(this).data("page") == 5){
    $("#next").addClass("hide");
  }
  else{
    $('#next').data('page', $(this).data("page")+1);
    $('#prev').data('page', $(this).data("page")-1);
  }
  if($("#prev").data("page") > 0 && $("#prev").hasClass("hide")){
    $("#prev").removeClass("hide");
  }
});


$(document).on("click", "#prev", function(){
  var pagenumber = $(this).data("page")+1;
  $("#page"+pagenumber).addClass("hide");
  $("#page"+$(this).data("page")).removeClass("hide");
  if($(this).data("page") == 0){
    $("#prev").addClass("hide");
  }
  else{
    $('#prev').data('page', $(this).data("page")-1);
    $('#next').data('page', $(this).data("page")+1);
  }
  if($("#next").data("page") < 5 && $("#next").hasClass("hide")){
    $("#next").removeClass("hide");
  }
});
```

```css
.hide{display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <h2 class="show" id="page0">Page #1</h2>
  <h2 class="hide" id="page1">Page #2</h2>
  <h2 class="hide" id="page2">Page #3</h2>
  <h2 class="hide" id="page3">Page #4</h2>
  <h2 class="hide" id="page4">Page #5</h2>
  <h2 class="hide" id="page5">Page #6</h2>

  <hr>

  <button id="prev" class="hide" data-page="0">&larr; PREV</button>
  <button id="next" data-page="1">NEXT &rarr;</button>
</div>
```